# TYPO3 Gridelements 11.0.0.dev error: Attempt to insert record on page '[root-level]' (0) where this table, tt_content, is not allowed

Tags: typo3, typo3-11.x, tx-gridelements

In Gridelements 11.0.0-dev and TYPO3 11.5.24 the following error occurs, if a content element is moved by drag and drop to an empty gridelement:

> Attempt to insert record on page '[root-level]' (0) where this table, tt_content, is not allowed.

In my opinion, the current page uid is not passed when pasting the content element.

Does anyone have a solution for this error?

Answer (score 2):

Gridelements is still not officially available for TYPO3 v11.5. If you rely on Gridelements, you should consider supporting the [crowdfunding campaign](https://coders.care/for/crowdfunding/gridelements). There you get access to a protected GitHub repository with a v11.5 compatible version.

Otherwise you should consider to migrate to alternatives like [EXT:container](https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/container/) (which is quite popular lately) or similar extensions.